# How to share a volume across multiple stages and jobs using containers

Tags: azure-pipelines

For an open source project, I use Azure Pipelines and run multiple jobs, each inside a custom Docker container, but with different environment variables. Everything works great, but I don't have enough debug data to root-cause some failures from the logs alone. Therefore, I'd like to publish an artifact (coredump, support bundle, etc.) when a job fails. While the conditional artifact publishing *appears* to be easy using two stages, the hard part is copying the artifacts from inside job's container to the host VM, using a volume. I've tried many alternatives by reading the docs, I couldn't make it work and couldn't find online an example for what I'm looking for. It might not even be possible, but I hope it is.

Let me show a simplified YAML file, to make sure we're all on the same page:

```
# This "resources" entry doesn't help, but I tried it.
#
# resources:
#   containers:
#   - container: artifacts-container
#     image: ubuntu:latest
#     volumes:
#        - /mnt/artifacts
#        - /mnt/artifacts:/mnt/artifacts   # tried also this way!

stages:
- stage: Test
  jobs:
    - job: A
      container: 'my-ubuntu-based-docker-container'
      services:                  # new stuff, it doesn't work as expected
        artifacts-service:       #
          image: ubuntu:latest   #
          volumes:               #
            - /mnt/artifacts     #

# I tried this approach with the "resources" above and still doesn't work
#
#     services:
#       artifacts-container: artifacts-container
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'
      variables:
         VAR1: blah
      steps:
        - script: /x/y/z
          displayName: run Z
        - script: touch /mnt/artifacts/hello-$SYSTEM_JOBIDENTIFIER
          displayName: create artifact
    - job: B
      container: 'my-ubuntu-based-docker-container'
      services:                  # new stuff, it doesn't work as expected
        artifacts-service:       #
          image: ubuntu:latest   #
          volumes:               #
            - /mnt/artifacts     #
# I tried this approach with the "resources" above and still doesn't work
#
#     services:
#       artifacts-container: artifacts-container

      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'
      variables:
         VAR1: blah-blah
      steps:
        - script: /x/y/z
          displayName: run Z
        - script: touch /mnt/artifacts/hello-$SYSTEM_JOBIDENTIFIER
          displayName: create artifact          

- stage: PublishArtifacts
  dependsOn: Test
  condition: always() # not(succeeded())
  jobs:
    - job: PublishCoreDumps
      services:
        artifacts-service:
          image: ubuntu:latest
          volumes:
            - /mnt/artifacts
# I tried this approach with the "resources" above and still doesn't work
#
#     services:
#       artifacts-container: artifacts-container
#    
      steps:
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          targetPath: /mnt/artifacts
          artifact: test-results
          publishLocation: pipeline
```

Note: I know that comments don't work often. Got burned by that already. I added them here, only for more context. I've also included additional experiments with "resources" that didn't work. The failure I get is like:

```
touch: cannot touch '/mnt/artifacts/hello-Test.A.__default': No such file or directory
```

Which I interpret as: `/mnt/artifacts` don't exist, because it hasn't been mounted. So, we clearly cannot create a file there. While, what I'd need is a way to write files from within the container, from multiple jobs, and have them published in case of failure.

That seems like natural feature to me, but *apparently* people don't use Azure Pipelines like that. Probably I'm missing more than one thing.

Maybe I need to install something inside my container? I'd be happy to do that, if it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Volumes` are useful for sharing data between `services`, or for persisting data between multiple runs of a job. However, you are using `Ubuntu-20.04` which is Microsoft-Hosted agent, volumes will `not be persisted` between jobs because the host machine is cleaned up after the job is completed.

You can refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#volumes) for more details.

[image]

Edit:

When you use `container job`, the steps are executed `inside the container` not agent machine.

[image]

Please make sure your container meets the [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#requirements).

With container job, you can directly publish the files(coredump, support bundle, etc.) as artifact, then download in your next stage.

Sample yaml:

```
stages:
- stage: Test
  jobs:
    - job: A
      container: ubuntu:20.04
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'
      variables:
         VAR1: blah
      steps:
      - script: |
          hostname    # to make sure the container by hostname
          echo test >> test1.txt

      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        inputs:
          targetPath: 'test1.txt'
          artifact: 'test'
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'

    - job: B
      container: ubuntu:20.04
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'
      variables:
         VAR1: blah
      steps:
      - script: |
          hostname    # to make sure the container by hostname
          echo test2 >> test2.txt

      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        inputs:
          targetPath: 'test2.txt'
          artifact: 'test2'
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Comment: OK, but does that mean that what I'm looking for simply cannot be done with Azure Pipelines (free version)? Is there any other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: If you like to use `volume`, you need to use self-hosted agent as it will not cleaned up. Or you can use the container job. I will add the sample in the reply.

Comment: Tested your approach and it works. Thanks! Just, the 2nd stage makes no sense anymore. There is no need to download the artifacts from 2nd stage if I just want to publish them.

Can you remove the PublishArtifacts stage from your solution in order to reduce the confusion for the other people?

Comment: Glad to know it helps! Sure, i have removed the 2nd stage. Happy coding!